# Interpreting Augmented Dickey Fuller and timeseries data

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am trying to understand time series. After using statsmodel ADF test, I get a p value of 0.97. My understanding is that the data cannot be modelled as a time series as the p value is high. Is this correct? If not, please help me understand why.

Comment: Hint: what is the null hypothesis and what is the alternative hypothesis of the ADF test? Given the $p$-value, which one do you stick with? Can it imply the data cannot be modelled as a time series?

Comment: P value is high and hence do not reject the null hypothesis and the data is non-stationary. My ADF statistics was higher than the Critical values. But with this knowledge alone can I say the data cannot be modeled as a times series problem?

Comment: I am still learning about time series. I plotted the data and I see an upward trend but no discernible local patterns.  What I am trying to understand is if the test says its non-stationary  then does it mean that there is no point in applying any type of time series modeling on the data.

Comment: If the data is a time series, you should model it accordingly. You should not ignore the fact that the observations are not i.i.d. but instead exhibit some form of dependence arising from the time ordering of the data. The result of the ADF test has no influence over this issue.

Comment: Thank you. So, though the data is non-stationary but show it shows a trend (slight increase over  4 years) time series can still be applied on it? I am little confused about why we check the stationarity then. Sorry if I am going around in circles with my questions. I am trying to understand.

Comment: Time series is a data type, not a method. If you have a time-ordered sequence of observations of the same object, you have a time series. What method to apply for analyzing it is another question.